# How to restart a docker stack container by cron?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I want to schedule a monthly restart of a docker container that has been set up with `docker stack deploy`.

```
$ docker stack ls
NAME           SERVICES   ORCHESTRATOR
hello-docker   1          Swarm
```

But there seems to be no `docker stack restart <name>` command.
So how could I tell docker to force a restart on a specific stack?

Or if not possible, restarting the whole `docker daemon` would also be fine from cron.

**Update**
The `scale` option in the linked question is a nice trick:

```
docker service scale myservice=0
docker service scale myservice=1
```

Comment: Do you mean the cron linux feature or some docker feature like cron?

Comment: I mean from a `crontab` job on the host system (ubuntu).

Comment: I think, on an external manager system you would use a tool like ansible:
`ansible swarm -m systemd -a "name=docker state=restarted`

Comment: `Or if not possible, restarting the whole docker daemon` → [`sudo systemctl restart docker`](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/)

Comment: crontab is so easy. Do you need to execute any shell command (docker in your case) at regular intervals on the same machine?

Comment: @rzlvmp but that does not work from within `crontab`!

Comment: @JRichardsz yes I want to restart the daemon or a single container on a regular basis each month.

Comment: check this to understand how cron works https://www.guru99.com/crontab-in-linux-with-examples.html  Basically you can execute any shell sentence at any day or interval. In your case could be:  0 0 1 * * docker service update --force 3xrdy2c7pfm3